# Команда move (asm)

Tags: ассемблер

Процедура `clear_cell_proc` очищает ячейку, заменяя пробелами. А что делает команда move?

```
move macro x,y
        push cx
        push ax
        push dx
        push bx
        mov ah,3
        int   10h
        mov ah,2
        add dx,x
        add dl,y
        int 10h 
        pop bx
        pop dx
        pop ax
        pop cx

    endm

 putchar macro symb  
        push bx
        push ax
        push dx  
        mov bl, symb
        mov ah,2
        xor dl,dl
        mov dl,bl
        int 21h
        pop dx
        pop ax   
        pop bx
    endm

clear_cell_proc proc       
            putchar ' '        
            move -1,0
            ret
        endp
```

Comment: http://www.codenet.ru/progr/dos/int_0009.php int 10h c AH=3 читает позицию курсора, потом уменьшает её на 1, int 10h c AH=2 устанавливает новую позицию курсора. То есть курсор перемещается на один символ назад. Хотя по мне это спорное название для макрокоманды, тк move есть в его командах.

Comment: Как происходит очистка символов в процедуре clear_cell_proc? как я понимаю мы заносим введённое число в стек потом с помощью putchar мы ставим пробел и далее сдвигаемся на один символ назад, а где собственно очистка символа, я что-то упустил ?  или же мы вместо удаляемого символа ставим пробел и далее сдвигаемся на шаг назад ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

move это не команда это макрос определенный в самом начале